# Installing intermediate CA in Debian

Tags: ssl-certificate

The SSL tester at sslcheck.globalsign.com says:

> Server configuration does not include all intermediate certificates

I found this page: 
http://yob.id.au/2013/02/06/trusting-new-ssl-certificates-in-debian.html
and they say I should do the following:
1.Open the affected domain in a browser and view the intermediate certificate
2.Export the certificate to a file with a .crt extension
3.Copy the file to your Debian box and place it in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
4.As root, run update-ca-certificates

It said:

> Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 1 added, 0 removed; done.
>   Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.

I did it, but it still isn't working. What should I do?

By the way, sometimes I can read (just like in the example above) that I should put certificates into  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates, other times that I should put them to  /etc/ssl/certs, so what is the correct location?

Comment: The issue is not that your server needs to trust this CA, but rather, that your webserver needs to be sending the either certificate chain to your clients.

Comment: OK, but how to accomplish this?

Comment: What is your webserver? Apache? nginx? IIS?

Comment: Apache on Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your apache's config files, search for this directive: `SSLCertificateChainFile` (if apache version 2.4.7 or lower) or `SSLCertificateFile` (if apache version 2.4.8 or higher)

The file pointed in that directive must contain the server certificate, followed by the issuer CA (and the issuer's issuer CA, and so on). It should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
qUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhqUC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Being the first certificate the server's, the second the intermediate CA's, etc.

Comment: I did it, and it didn't work:( Please note, that before that, I added SSL through DirectAdmin, maybe there is a mess right now? Additionally, in httpd-ssl.conf there is a line like this: SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/server.ca with 6 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' lines, and I don't know where they came from.

Comment: OK, nevermind, I did this through Direct Admin.